Solidity ERC721, how to correctly extends several base contracts
I'm very new to solidity programming, and I'm following an old tutorial based on 0.5.0.
I've tried to modify the tutorial for a recent version.
I'm trying to create a ECR721 token, and I have code that works. I am however extending from ERC721, ERC721URIStorage and ERC721Enumerable, and I believe there are some issues with methods from those contracts.
Did I correctly resolve these issues, or am I missing some key concepts from the solidity language?
How is super resolved for those methods? It's not clear to me which supercontract would be used.
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import { ERC721 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import { ERC721URIStorage } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import { ERC721Enumerable } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract MemoryToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Enumerable {

    mapping (uint256 => address) private _tokenOwner;
    mapping(uint256 tokenId => string) private _tokenURIs;

    constructor() ERC721("Memory Token", "MEMORY") {
    }

    function mint(address _to, string memory _tokenURI) public returns(bool) {
        uint _tokenId = totalSupply() + 1;
        _mint(_to, _tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);
        return true;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) returns (string memory) {
        return super.tokenURI(_tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage) returns (bool) {
        return
            interfaceId == type(ERC721).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(ERC721URIStorage).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(ERC721Enumerable).interfaceId ||
            super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function _update(address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) returns (address) {
        return super._update(to, tokenId, auth);
    }

    function _increaseBalance(address account, uint128 amount) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._increaseBalance(account, amount);
    }

}

